# Can we reopen the question about changing ownership of the /usr/bin, /usr/lib, and /usr/share directories?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

The question [I set /usr/bin, /usr/lib, and /usr/share to be owned by my regular user and now I am getting interesting errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/874782/i-set-usr-bin-usr-lib-and-usr-share-to-be-owned-by-my-regular-user-and-now) is current closed as a duplicate of [What if I accidentally run command “chmod -R” on system directories (/, /etc, …)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc).

I believe the two questions are different and they shouldn't be a duplicate of one another. Although they are similar, the first one is somewhat easier to recover because the contents of those three directories are mostly (and most probably always) owned by root. And recovering from such an issue is just a matter of logging into recovery mode and fixing the ownership problem as Kaz Wolfe's [answer explains](https://askubuntu.com/a/874796/8698).
While in the second question, the system is almost completely damaged, and it's much tougher to recover from, as shown from the answer to those questions.

Comment: Just a matter of that ... With the final step being "reboot and pray". Yeah, right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure. I'm not doing anything at the moment, just thinking out aloud.

- I've answered a few questions on "chmod/chown-gone-wild" questions and [I usually lean towards reinstallation](https://askubuntu.com/a/452868/449). It's faster and safer.
- But I'm normally talking about **system-wide** changes.
- [It's `/var/` that is most complex](https://askubuntu.com/a/343308/449).
- Most other directories are a much more simple `root:` pattern until you get to `/home`
- But even in `/usr/`, there are outliers:

  ```
  $ sudo find /usr/  -not \( -user 0 -group 0 \) -not -path "/usr/*/node_modules/*" -not -path "/usr/local/lib/python*" -printf "%p,%u:%g\n" | grep -viE "(squeeze|rabbitmq|nginx|lxc|postfix)" | sort -u | column -t -c 80 -s ,
  /usr/bin/AfterShot3X64                                   oli:oli
  /usr/bin/bsd-write                                       root:tty
  /usr/bin/chage                                           root:shadow
  /usr/bin/crontab                                         root:crontab
  /usr/bin/dotlockfile                                     root:mail
  /usr/bin/expiry                                          root:shadow
  /usr/bin/mlocate                                         root:mlocate
  /usr/bin/smerge                                          501:staff
  /usr/bin/ssh-agent                                       root:ssh
  /usr/bin/wall                                            root:tty
  /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper              root:messagebus
  /usr/lib/evolution/camel-lock-helper-1.2                 root:mail
  /usr/lib/libvte9/gnome-pty-helper                        root:utmp
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter              root:utmp
  /usr/local/share/emacs                                   root:staff
  /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp                         root:staff
  /usr/local/share/fonts                                   root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml/declaration                        root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml/dtd                                root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml/entities                           root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml/misc                               root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml                                    root:staff
  /usr/local/share/sgml/stylesheet                         root:staff
  /usr/local/share/texmf                                   root:staff
  /usr/local/share/xml/declaration                         root:staff
  /usr/local/share/xml/entities                            root:staff
  /usr/local/share/xml/misc                                root:staff
  /usr/local/share/xml                                     root:staff
  /usr/local/share/xml/schema                              root:staff
  /usr/sbin/postdrop                                       root:postdrop
  /usr/sbin/postqueue                                      root:postdrop
  /usr/sbin/pppd                                           root:dip
  /usr/share/applications/AfterShot3X64.desktop            oli:oli
  /usr/share/applications/sublime_merge.desktop            501:staff
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/sublime-merge.png  501:staff
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sublime-merge.png    501:staff
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/sublime-merge.png  501:staff
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/sublime-merge.png    501:staff
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sublime-merge.png    501:staff
  /usr/share/mime/packages/AfterShot3X64.xml               oli:oli
  /usr/share/pixmaps/AfterShot3X64.png                     oli:oli
  /usr/share/ppd/custom                                    root:lpadmin
  ```
- Some of this is common some is crank from my computer. Note I excluded node_modules (which was *appalling*) and similarly python (abused by `sudo pip3` over the years). These were *thousands* of files owned by $USER.

#### So what next?

I'm not sure. **Is that answer good enough** that our collective advice to people changes from [*You Done Messed Up A-Aron!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6rZfpSL1RQ) to *You can fix it*?

I can't speak for this user's system before *the incident*, but whenever people deliberately start tearing down walls in the permissions, I worry about the other things they've done to get where they are.

I'd personally probably still recommend backup and reinstall.

Comment: Dunno about that answer, but there is one I'd suggest is good enough: [terdon's here](https://askubuntu.com/a/884657/158442). It's for `/etc`, but is sufficiently flexible and should get the base system working enough for everything else to be fixed by package reinstallation/upgrade.

Comment: But if we consider your output as an example, most of the files are owned by root, it's only the group that isn't `root` (I'm not sure about the `501` user id, I don't have that in my case. Maybe it was because of a removed package?). So if you run `chown someuser` and not `chown someuser:` (which is the case in the question I linked) the possibility to revert back is still there. I'm not saying a solution is always possible, but most of the time it is. And users can feel less _panicky_ as their system isn't really bricked.

Comment: If that's what they've done, then it may be possible to reverse. The situation I'm trying to avoid here is somebody doing more than what they're admitting to (or people reading the Q&A later on). It isn't difficult to (eg) get the system to stop *complaining* about permissions (eg fixing the sudoers file) but leave the rest of it wide open to abuse. Perhaps where specific fixes are possible we put a `DANGER ⚡ HIGH VOLTAGE` warning that spells out exactly the scenario that answer applies to.